# Will this matrix be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

**Suppose that:**

- $A$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix, with diagonal elements *strictly positive* and summing to one.
- $b$ is a $1\times n$ vector, with elements *non-negative* and summing to one (there might be zeros).

**Question :** Is the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$-sized block matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & b\\b' & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

invertible ?

If no, would it be under some ctricter condition that i did not thought of ?

Comment: Try some gauss operation, it will be clear then

Comment: Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 \\ 1/2
\end{pmatrix}$. Then your $3\times 3$ matrix is not invertible. I think you need at least $A$ to be invertible, but maybe another assumption is needed...

Comment: Hey @Fabien, I supposed that A is diagonal, which makes it invertible (and pos-def), since i also supposed all it's elements were positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your matrix (which I will call $M$) is invertible.  To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that $A$ is invertible, as is its [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)
$$
M/A = 0 - b'A^{-1}b = -\|A^{-1/2}b\|^2.
$$
We compute $\det(M) = -\det(A)\cdot b'A^{-1}b$.

---

By block-matrix multiplication, we have
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1} M \pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1}^T = \pmatrix{A & 0\\0&-b'A^{-1}b}
$$
Taking the inverse of both sides yields
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1}^{-T} M^{-1} \pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1} = \pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0&-(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}}^{-1} \implies\\
 M^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1}^{T}\pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0&-(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}}
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1} \implies\\
 M^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{I & 0\\-b'A^{-1} & 1}^{T}\pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}b'A^{-1}&-(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}} \implies\\
M^{-1} = \pmatrix{A^{-1} - A^{-1}b(b'A^{-1}b)b'A^{-1} & -(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}A^{-1}b\\
(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}b'A^{-1} & (b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}}.
$$

We also could have computed this directly from [the formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties), since
$$
M^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{A^{-1} + A^{-1} B (M/A)^{-1} C A^{-1} & - A^{-1} B (M/A)^{-1} \\ - (M/A)^{-1} CA^{-1} & (M/A)^{-1}}\\
= \pmatrix{A^{-1} - A^{-1}b(b'A^{-1}b)b'A^{-1}& -(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}A^{-1}b\\
(b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}b'A^{-1} & (b'A^{-1}b)^{-1}}
$$

---

We could also compute the inverse using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).  In particular:

Let $v$ denote the matrix $b$ with a $1$ appended to the end. Let $D$ denote the matrix $A$ with an extra row and column of zeros added and a $-2$ in the bottom right. Let $V$ denote the matrix whose columns are $e_n = (0,\dots,0,1)^T$ and $v$.

By the identity, we have
$$
M^{-1} = (D + VV^T)^{-1}
= D^{-1} + 
D^{-1}V
(I_2 + V^TD^{-1}V)
V^TD^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Yes, A is clearly invertible by the hypothesis, it's even positive definite. Thanks for computing the determinant of my matrix helps a lot. What now about it's inverse ?

Comment: I've added some initial thoughts on that

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: right after "By block-matrix multiplication, we have", you miss a minus sign in the left down value of the last matrix

Comment: I see that, fixed it.  I still think something has gone wrong.

Comment: I figured it out, the mistake was in the final multiplication.

Comment: I also fixed the second approach so that no limit is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i checked and i agree with your computations